# insert, select and update in a single query - SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want from a ngrams (HashMap) to extract all values in a database. My question is how can I implement better the extract function. The execution of this chunk of code is slow because the java program must check each time an entry of the HashMap if exists in the table. If exists then it must select the previous frequency from the table and add this with the new one.

Could I change the three functions (update,insert,check) in order to make this process better?

here is the code for the connection with the database

```
public boolean insert(String w1, String w2, String w3, String w4, Integer f, float rf) throws SQLException{
   ...
   String sql = "INSERT INTO fourgrams " +
           "VALUES("+w1 + "," + w2 + "," + w3 + "," + w4 + "," + f + ',' + rf + ")" 
   ...
}
public boolean update(String w1, String w2, String w3, String w4, Integer f) throws SQLException{
   ... 
   String sql = "UPDATE fourgrams  " +
           "SET frequency =" + f + " WHERE gram1=" + w1 +
           " AND gram2=" + w2 + " AND gram3=" + w3 +
           " AND gram3=" + w3;
   ...
}
public int check(String w1, String w2, String w3, String w4) throws  SQLException{
   ...
   String sql = "SELECT frequency FROM fourgrams " +
           "WHERE gram1=" + w1 +
           " AND gram2=" + w2 + " AND gram3=" + w3 +
           " AND gram3=" + w3;

   ...
}
```

And here is the code that I have problem

```
 public void extract(Database myDB) throws SQLException{
   Iterator it = ngrams.entrySet().iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){
      ...
      int fr=myDB.check(...);
      if (fr == -1)
      {
         myDB.insert(...);
      }else{
         myDB.update(...);
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Inserts. In your loop build a single insert of the form

```
INSERT INTO fourgrams VALUES
 (w1..),
 (w1..),
 (w1..)..
```

2) Updates. Create temp table the same way and update from that table

```
UPDATE fourgrams 
JOIN temp ON fourgrams.gram1= temp.gram1 AND ...
SET frequency = temp.frequency
```

If your dataset are too big you may wish to transfer them to server machine as CSV and LOAD INFILE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose that LOAD INFILE is what I need.